# How to get a Timer to work in it's own class for a simple game

Tags: java, timer

So I wanted to write the basics for a 2D game so I could look back at later if I forget and so I could create one without having to look over the same tutorials over and over again.

Since the first game I made was a snake game almost a year ago(I've asked for help with this before), I looked back on it to find quite the mess! I only used one class for everything and I neglected to use comments to tell myself what each part of the code is doing what.

I was using the tutorial from: http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=25802.0, but they use bufferStrategy, which I haven't used before, and Key Event / Key Adapter,which I was told to use ActionListener for the Snake Game instead.

I know the main classes that I would be changing are ButtonHandler, Draw, and Player. I've already edited a few things: added limits to how far the square can go (so it doesn't go off screen) and a Variables class so that the other classes inherit it so I can change the size of the screen and square easily.  I've tried coping and pasting the Timer into it's own class, but since I have very little knowledge of how to use a Timer, it doesn't work (obviously).

My questions are:
Can bufferStrategy work with Timer? Could I put a Timer with ActionListener in it's own class? Can bufferStrategy work like a Timer?

Oh, and on top of that, what's the best way to make a start screen and inventory screen? How does it fit in with the main screen or should I just make a separate screen that pops up for both (if that is easier)?

Edit:

Alright, sorry, I was out watching a play. Here's the Draw class from the tutorial plus some edits for the variables. I was wondering which class the Timer would go into.  Since the bufferStrategy was done in the Draw class, would the Timer be there as well? This also includes my unfinished version of a start screen.

Draw class

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Draw extends Variables
{
  JFrame frame;
  Canvas canvas;

  BufferStrategy bufferStrategy;

  private int WIDTH = w;
  private int HEIGHT = h;

  private int PWIDTH = pw;
  private int PHEIGHT = ph;
  Color start = Color.decode("#00BFFF");


  Draw(){
    frame = new JFrame("Game");
    JPanel panel = (JPanel) frame.getContentPane();
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
    panel.setLayout(null);

    canvas = new Canvas();
    canvas.setBounds(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    canvas.setIgnoreRepaint(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();

    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    panel.add(canvas);
    canvas.createBufferStrategy(2);
    bufferStrategy = canvas.getBufferStrategy();
    canvas.requestFocus();

    canvas.setBackground(Color.black);
    canvas.addKeyListener(new ButtonHandler());
  }
  void render() {
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) bufferStrategy.getDrawGraphics();
    if (startScreen == 0)
    {
      g.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
      render(g);
      g.dispose();
      bufferStrategy.show();
    }
    else
    {
      canvas.setBackground(start);
    }
  }
  protected void render(Graphics2D g){
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.fillRect(Instances.player.getX(), Instances.player.getY(), PWIDTH, PHEIGHT);
  }
}
```

Comment: I feel that your question is currently far too broad for Stack Overflow. I see five different questions within your single question, and the first three (about BufferStrategy and Timer) seem to be topics that you can answer yourself if you try writing some code with those classes. The other set of questions (about start screens and inventory screens) seems to be more a matter of opinion than something with a definite answer. Could you possible refine your question (or write new question[s]) with more objective topics that can be answered definitely and precisely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can bufferStrategy work with Timer?

Yes.

> Could I put a Timer with ActionListener in it's own class?

Yes.

> Can bufferStrategy work like a Timer?

No.

Post some code with a more specific question for a more detailed answer.

Comment: thanks this helps quite a bit! I've posted a more specific question now :D